# Error: AWS CLI SSH Certificate Verify Failed _ssl.c:581

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssl-certificate, command-line-interface

I am trying to use the sync command from my file system to S3 on a Windows 2008 R2 server.
I have previously had no problem running this command on multiple local machines:

AWS S3 SYNC 'File system Name' S3://'S3 file directory name'

However when I try to run it from this box I get this error:

*[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)*

Every forum I see is using python scripts but I am just using the simple CLI commands.

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 3):

If you are running aws cli commands on Windows, above given commands i.e (sudo pip) will not work.

1) TO avoid "[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)" error 
   on cli you can use the format like :

> > **AWS *[aws-service-name]* --no-verify-ssl *[functions]***

2) Then your cli command for S3 Sync becomes:

> > AWS S3 --no-verify-ssl SYNC 'File system Name' S3://'S3 file directory name'

Answer (score 2):

This worked around the issue for me on ubuntu 14.04. I cannot confirm if it is an ideal/complete solution:

```
sudo pip uninstall certifi
sudo pip install certifi==2015.04.28
```

From here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1499